# HP ProLiant DL365 G5 fan noise

Tags: hardware, hp, hp-proliant, fan

I have an HP Proliant DL365, I know it is an old thing. But it works fine for what we have here.

But the last time this thing makes a lot of noise and a few lights glow up: 
[image]

When I search in the eventviewer I see no strange things, no errors or warnings. 
I can also find not much on the lights in the image I displayed above.

Maybe you have a clue what is possibly wrong here with the lights and the lots of FAN noise.

Comment: That thing looks _filthy_. I'd be worried about dust buildup in there clogging stuff up.

Comment: It's a bit filthy indeed, I should clean that

Comment: I'm not going to suggest that taking a can of air to your server innards will fix the fans, but it certainly wouldn't *hurt*.

Comment: Hopefully needless warning NOT to blow compressed air on the fans whilest allowing them to spin.

Answer (score 15):

This is a photo of the Systems Insight Display (SID) for an HP ProLiant DL365 G5 server.

The SID provides a visual indicator of the status and health of your server. From the [photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SLE4U.jpg) you posted, it's very clear that the lower right-hand LED on the SID is illuminated...

This is for **FAN 3**, which means that one of your redundant fan modules is dead and the other fans are running at a higher speed to compensate.

[image]

Your best options at this point are:

- Open the SID display to see if any other components are bad.
- Install HP management agents which can report system health to you.
- Log onto the ILO of the server, as it also contains logs about system health.
- Source a replacement fan for this server.

The server actually has NINE fans in groups of THREE. So in this case, you would need to replace the entire module ([HP part #412212-001](http://www.ebay.com/sch/i.html?_from=R40&_trksid=p2060353.m570.l1313.TR1.TRC0.A0.H0.X412212-001.TRS0&_nkw=412212-001&_sacat=0)).

[image]

Comment: It's not just "the fans are running faster to compensate", it's that the BMC goes into failsafe mode and runs all the fans full-speed if it detects any dead/missing ones, just to be sure.

Answer (score 8):

From the Docs -

Top light - Internal health LED

> Green = System health is normal.
>   Amber = System health is degraded. To identify the component in
>   a degraded state, refer to "HP Systems Insight Display and LEDs".
>   Red = System health is critical. To identify the component in a
>   critical state, refer to "HP Systems Insight Display and LEDs".
>   Off = System health is normal (when in standby mode).

Second light - External health LED
(power supply)

> Green = Power supply health is normal.
>   Amber = Power redundancy failure occurred.
>   Off = Power supply health is normal when in standby mode.

I'm guessing you have two PSUs in the unit and the second light is telling you one has failed. This would lead to an increase in noise as earlier (And I think current) HP servers effectively used both unless one failed and then this has to work twice as hard. Twice as hard means twice the heat, meaning higher fan speeds are needed.

As for the first light, there is a small display that pops out just below the cd/dvd tray. Push it to eject it and this will tell you more about what is causing that warning.

Comment: did yo have complete reference for Server LED lights??