# HP ProLiant DL360 G5 - no post, no beeps

Tags: hp-proliant

since i'm a total "server stuff" beginner i decided to get started with a used server so i got an HP ProLiant DL360 Gen 5.

I plugged the power cables, keyboard, mouse and a VGA monitor and turned it on just to realize it can't POST, it stays in a situation with fans spinning at 100%. No beeps either.

At first i had problems with ILO too, i used the reset switch to reset the configuration. Now i can log in to ilo but it does not help, system health is "ok" but the system is still in the 100% fan speed and no post.

I'm doing this tests with no HD, DVD, minimum RAM and power supply.

Any suggestions?

Comment: What did HP support say?

Comment: @eeaa HP support won't _support_ a server this old. It went end-of-life in 2009.

Answer (score 1):

Look at the Integrated Management Log menu in the ILO. It will tell you what's wrong with the server.

You can look at the slide-out [Systems Insight Display (SID)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XWxm9.png) to see the health of the components.

Otherwise, talk to the party that sold you this equipment.

Also see: [HP ProLiant DL365 G5 fan noise](https://serverfault.com/questions/749339/hp-proliant-dl365-g5-fan-noise/749404#749404)

Answer (score 0):

No beep and nothing else point to me to a motherboars problem.

If you remove totally the ram does it beep ? if no then motherboard.

As its a new buy you better contact the vendor. If you cant check on ebay for the same model to have a replacement part.